# mysql table gets hanged after update sql

Tags: mysql

I am having a mysql MyISAM table with more than 2 million records. I am running a shell script for updating each row this table and the job is completed. However when i am opening this table in any mysql gui tool or try to run a select query on it, the mysql server gets hanged. Any idea, how to proceed on this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a commit done at the end of your shell script? Could it be a problem with some locking?

Comment: This is not a transaction table. Just a MyIsam table and there is no commit and lock.

Comment: add a limit clause to your select query and check if it works `select * from tableName limit 10`